# How to swap two words with sed and with multiple delimiters?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, sed

Just letters are accepted in words, any other characters are delimiters.
I want to exchange the first word with the third word.

```
sed -E 's/([A-Za-z]+) [^A-Za-z] ([A-Za-z]+) [^A-Za-z] ([A-Za-z]+)/\3 \2 \1/' filename
```

I wrote this but don't works correctly

Example:

```
I 4want5to%change
```

This string I want to change to:

```
to 4want5I%change
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using character class `[[:alpha:]]` to match uppercase and lowercase and the negation `[^[:alpha:]]` to match all others:

```
sed -r 's/^([^[:alpha:]]*)([[:alpha:]]+)([^[:alpha:]]+[[:alpha:]]+[^[:alpha:]]+)([[:alpha:]]+)([^[:alpha:]]*)/\1\4\3\2\5/' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^[:alpha:]]*)([[:alpha:]]+)([^[:alpha:]]+[[:alpha:]]+[^[:alpha:]]+)([[:alpha:]]+)([^[:alpha:]]*)/\1\4\3\2\5/' <<<'I 4want5to%change'
to 4want5I%change

$ sed -r 's/^([^[:alpha:]]*)([[:alpha:]]+)([^[:alpha:]]+[[:alpha:]]+[^[:alpha:]]+)([[:alpha:]]+)([^[:alpha:]]*)/\1\4\3\2\5/' <<<'4I 4want5to%change'
4to 4want5I%change

$ sed -r 's/^([^[:alpha:]]*)([[:alpha:]]+)([^[:alpha:]]+[[:alpha:]]+[^[:alpha:]]+)([[:alpha:]]+)([^[:alpha:]]*)/\1\4\3\2\5/' <<<'Spring&summer^winter'
winter&summer^Spring
```

Comment: What advantage do you expect to get with the fifth backreference?  It's not doing anything....

Comment: @Wildcard 5th one is matching `%change`

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot, but still don't work for the example `Spring&summer^winter`.

Comment: @Uninnu try my answer; it will work on that input.

Comment: @heemayl, your 5th capture group *requires* a trailing non-alpha character, which was not part of the problem description.  That's why it fails on `Spring&summer^winter`.

Comment: @Wildcard Yeah, didn't notice that..fixed

Comment: @Uninnu Check my edits..

Comment: @heemayl you still have a completely pointless 5th capture group.

Answer (score 1):

Take out the spaces, and fix your backreferences to preserve your delimiters.  Also, since you have a delimiter "`<space>4`", you obviously need to allow multiple "delimiter" characters in a row as delimiters.

You should specify that this is at the start of a line.

So instead of:

```
sed -E 's/([A-Za-z]+) [^A-Za-z] ([A-Za-z]+) [^A-Za-z] ([A-Za-z]+)/\3 \2 \1/' filename
```

Use:

```
sed -E 's/^([A-Za-z]+)([^A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z]+[^A-Za-z]+)([A-Za-z]+)/\3\2\1/' filename
```

Comment: This will fail for many patterns e.g. `4I 4want5to%change`

Comment: @heemayl, he said swap the first and third fields.  His own example data shows that either empty fields are disallowed, or else he really meant first and *fourth* field.  I answered for the case where empty fields are disallowed, e.g. consecutive non-letter characters (such as `<space>4`) are counted as a single delimiter...as I mentioned in my answer.  The example in your comment doesn't match the parameters of the problem he described.

Comment: Actually, humorously enough, from a literal reading of the problem statement my code *does* handle `4I 4want5to%change` correctly—it swaps the first field (between start of string and `4`) and third field (between the space and the second `4`), in other words it swaps two empty fields and leaves the input unchanged.  ;)

Comment: Space is allowed as delimiter.

Comment: @Uninnu, you mean space is allowed as *part of* a delimiter?  Or a single space by itself is a delimiter?  Because if a single space is a delimiter, then the third field of `I 4want5to%change` is "want", not "to".  I assumed that the  space and 4 *together* made up a single delimiter of that line.

Comment: Can be the part of the delimiter or delimiter by itself. Both are options.

Comment: @Uninnu, that's how my answer works already...did you try my answer?  It is actually cleaner than the answer you accepted....

Comment: Yes, I tried. Don't works for example for this: `#One two three four`. Doesn't changed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not married to sed, this is a good job for perl: here I'm also providing the ability to specify which words you want to swap

if "file" contains

```
I 4want5to%change
#One two three four
Spring&summer^winter
```

Then this command

```
$ perl -lnse '
    BEGIN {
        $i = ($first - 1) * 2;
        $j = ($second - 1) * 2;
    }
    @tokens = /([[:alpha:]]*)([^[:alpha:]]*)/g;
    ($tokens[$i], $tokens[$j]) = ($tokens[$j], $tokens[$i]);
    print join "", @tokens;
' -- -first=1 -second=3 file
```

outputs

```
to 4want5I%change
two#One  three four
winter&summer^Spring
```